# How to schedule a NSOperation to the head of queue and let all other operations waiting for it?

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have a `NSOperationQueue` that is concurrent. For a specific `NSOperation`, if it fails, I want to immediately retry this operation at the highest priority, and suspend all other operations until it succeeded.

I can think of scheduling a operation with higher priority, but how can I make all other operations waiting for this one in an efficient way? Changing all remaining operations dependencies seem too time consuming.

Comment: You may take a look into the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1411204-queuepriority) for ideas how to solve it.

Comment: @Rob Thanks Rob. My queue is concurrent. How to suspend the concurrent queue while having the retry operation running on another queue?

Comment: As an aside, you reference `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation`. In Swift you should use `OperationQueue` and `Operation`, without the `NS` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches:

1. One simple approach, which cuts the Gordian knot, is to just make the task that may require multiple attempts not finish until the retries are done (i.e., incorporate the retry login within the operation, itself). Then schedule the first task with a barrier, schedule the subsequent tasks, and that way none of the subsequent tasks will be able to run until the first one finishes (including all of its retries).
2. Alternatively, if you want to make the retry tasks separate operations, but do not want to use dependencies, you could add the subsequent tasks to a separate, suspended, queue:

   ```swift
   let taskQueue = OperationQueue()
   taskQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4
   taskQueue.isSuspended = true

   for i in 0 ..< 20 {
       taskQueue.addOperation {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Then, add the task that may require retries to another queue (i.e., obviously, one that is not suspended):

   ```swift
   func attempt(_ count: Int = 0) {
       retryQueue.addOperation {
           ...

           if isSuccessful {
               taskQueue.isSuspended = false
           } else {
               attempt(count + 1)
           }

           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   When you do this, the first operation will un-suspend the task queue when the necessary criteria have been met:

   [image]
3. For the sake of completeness, the other alternative is to subclass `Operation` and make the `isReady` logic not only return its `super` implementation, but also observe some property. E.g.

   ```swift
   class WaitingOperation: Operation {
       @objc dynamic var canStart = false

       var object: NSObject
       var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

       let taskId: Int

       override var isReady: Bool { super.isReady && canStart }

       init<T>(object: T, canStartTasksKeyPath keyPath: KeyPath<T, Bool>, taskId: Int) where T: NSObject {
           self.object = object
           self.taskId = taskId
           super.init()
           observer = object.observe(keyPath, options: [.initial, .new]) { [weak self] _, changes in
               if let newValue = changes.newValue {
                   self?.canStart = newValue
               }
           }
       }

       override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
           var set = super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)

           if key == #keyPath(isReady) {
               set.insert(#keyPath(canStart))
           }

           return set
       }

       override func main() {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```swift
   @objc dynamic var canStartTasks = false

   func begin() {
       let queue = OperationQueue()
       queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4

       for i in 0 ..< 20 {
           queue.addOperation(WaitingOperation(object: self, canStartTasksKeyPath: \.canStartTasks, taskId: i))
       }

       let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
       attempt()

       func attempt(_ count: Int = 0) {
           queue.addOperation { [self] in
               ...

               if notSuccessful {
                   attempt(count + 1)
               } else {
                   canStartTasks = true
               }

               ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Rob! This is really helpful. One question about the first approach. Since Apple deprecated `operations`, is there a reliable way to add dependencies when my operation realizes it needs retrying?

Comment: And also for the barrier approach, since `OperationQueue` only has `addBarrierBlock`, which adds the operation to the very end, I guess if there're already subsequent operations after the one that needs retrying, there's no way we can add a barrier block right?

Comment: Yeah, while I was advocating using `operations` to iterate through, updating dependencies, as you point out, that will be deprecated, so I have removed that from my list of suggestions, above.

Comment: @Patroclus - the barrier approach works iff the first operation simply doesn't finish until the retries have been exhausted (or, obviously, if it succeeds). You can't use barrier approach if you plan on later adding a separate retry operation. But it works perfectly if the retry process is embedded within the first operation.

Comment: Thank you Rob. That makes sense.